# Recovering files that do not appear in the Recycle Bin, but are in the $Recycle.bin folder on external drive

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, recycle-bin

**Problem:**
I have an NTFS external drive with a `$Recycle.bin` folder on the root (`E:\$Recycle.bin`) that has about 70Gb worth of data. For whatever reason, the folder is no longer a hidden system folder, and no Windows machine I have used the drive on will show the files in the actual Recycle Bin.

**What I Want To Do:** I want to at least view the Recycle Bin files from this external drive.
All of the help articles I have read just talk about deleting the folder altogether.
I plan on reformatting the drive, but first I need to see if there are any important deleted files.

**What Didn't Work:**

- Recuva - didn't see any of my files
- Resetting the external drive's Recycle Bin via command prompt and moving the old `$Recycle.bin` files into the new external `$Recycle.bin` folder (I didn't read this anywhere, just made it up on my own)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I noticed multiple recycle bins ($RECYCLE.BIN and a folder called "RECYCLER").

My solution was to:

1. Use another file management tool (like Total Commander) and copy the contents of these  folders (i.e., old "deleted" files) to another folder.
2. I then deleted the $RECYCLE.BIN folder(s)
3. I then ejected and reinserted the drive (this might be optional)

This is not the "correct" solution (it must be that the registry settings for the S-##### folder in the $RECYCLE.BIN folder are wrong), but it does cause Windows to "reset" itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, try a Linux machine or even a LiveCD/DVD to see if the files can be accessed.

If not, try data recovery utils such as [GetDataBack for NTFS](http://www.runtime.org), [RStudio](http://rstudio.org) and [Zero Assumption Recovery](http://www.z-a-recovery.com).